# MySql regexp on column with html

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table with HTML content in which I need to select all rows containing a span element with the CSS class "glyphicon glyphicon-film" with some text content, but exclude all rows without content or just containing a white space.

These rows should NOT match:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"> </span>
<span class="hypo-link-target" data-link-target-id="1379">Hammartå</span>
```

These rows should match:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">nån text</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">Nån Text</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">NÅN TEXT</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp;nån text</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp;Nån Text</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp; nån text</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp; Nån Text</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"> nån text</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"> Nån Text</span>
```

The query I have at the moment:

```
select * from Section 
where (Text regexp '(span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp;.+</span>)' 
or Text regexp 'span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">[a-zA-Z][|å|ä|ö|Å|Ä|Ö]+</span>');
```

Which regexp should I use to get the desired result?

**UPDATE:**
Based on suggestions in the answer I ended up with this query which I think works for all cases. This query will also match on rows with two or more span elements where some elements are correct and some are not, like this one:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp;Nån Text</span>more content here... and a correct span <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp;</span>

select * from Section 
where Text regexp 'span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp;.+</span>' 
        or (Text regexp 'span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ ]+</span>'
and Text not regexp 'span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"> </span>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `[a-zA-Z][|å|ä|ö|Å|Ä|Ö]` matches a string beginning with an ASCII letter, followed by any mixture of `|åäöÅÄÖ`. You want to match a string of any combination of these characters, as well as spaces, which you left out. That would be `[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ ]+`.

`|` is not used inside `[]` to specify alternatives, since `[]` is already specifying alternative characters.

```
select * from Section 
where (Text regexp 'span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">&nbsp;.+</span>' 
        or Text regexp 'span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film">[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ ]+</span>')
and Text not regexp 'span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"> +</span>';
```

The last condition is needed to prevent `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"> </span>` from matching.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc81ae/2)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it didn't work. With your change I only got match on the rows containing "&nbsp;xxx", nothing else.

Comment: "space" is still missing from the regexp.

Comment: @poa I've updated the answer and added a demo showing it works.

Comment: @Barmar ahh yes this was a lot better. With a slight modification I think it works fine now.  I updated the question with the query I think is good. Thanks.